# How do I call success callback on fetching collection from getPage in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my code , after fetching the collection from getPage , I need the data from the fetch function which getPage uses to retrieve data.

```
collection.getPage(0).done({
    success: function(collection, data, xhr){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(model, response, options){

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `getPage` function returns a jQuery [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object or promise.

If that's the case, you should use `.then` rather than `.done`:

```
function success(data) {
  console.log(data)
}

function error(jqxhr) {
  console.error('oh no!', jqhxr)
}

collection.getPage(0).then(success, error)
```

`$.Deferred.done` accepts a single function argument. It will be called on success only. `.then` accepts a success callback and error callback.

Comment: This would be true if success and error are the callback functions written by me but I need to get data from fetch() function which getPage delegates to and the fetch options hash takes success and error callbacks.

<br>
[link]http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch
<br>
[link]https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator
<br>
In the above link , it is mentioned that All of the get*Page methods accept the same options Backbone.Collection#fetch accepts under server-mode? Can we use this pull data from fetch() ?

Comment: You can provide callbacks or use the promise style (which leads to cleaner code). If getPage returns the return value of fetch, this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @joews . I got it to work calling 
`collection.getPage(0).success(function(result){ console.log(result);  }`